# win 10 Qt C++ program calls Python program how to package and distribute

Tags: python, c++

In win10 Qt environment, C++ program calls Python program how to package and distribute, can run this program on another machine without Python environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pyinstaller to make a .exe file out of your .py. And a .exe file can run on every windows Pc.

Comment: Brother, I want to call Python API in my C++ programs, not just Python programs